# Why does dotnet publish fail when using the pwsh task, but not PowerShell@2?

Tags: .net, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dotnet-tool

Using Azure Pipelines, I have the following step in a job running on the `windows-2022` vmImage:

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    $config = "${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}"
    $runtime = "${{ parameters.runtime }}"

    dotnet publish WebApp `
      --configuration $buildConfiguration `
      --runtime $runtime `
      --output publish `
      --self-contained true
  displayName: dotnet publish for ${{ parameters.runtime }}
```

This weirdly results in the following failure:

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\a3fb3cbf-4c5d-4ee6-b4a8-979fceec0fab.ps1'"
MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
    Full command line: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -target:Publish -property:PublishDir=D:\a\1\s\publish -property:SelfContained=True -property:_CommandLineDefinedSelfContained=true -property:Configuration=--runtime WebApp linux-x64 -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\dotnet.dll'
  Switches appended by response files:
Switch: linux-x64
```

What's concerning about the above information is the `-property:Configuration=--runtime WebApp linux-x64` part. Looks like there's some weird parsing issue, perhaps. I tried putting the `dotnet publish` part all on one line (by removing the back-ticks) and I still get the same error. I tried many permutations of the inline script but had no success.

What makes this even weirder is if I add the bottom 3 new properties to the step:

```
- pwsh: |
    $config = "${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}"
    $runtime = "${{ parameters.runtime }}"

    dotnet publish WebApp `
      --configuration $buildConfiguration `
      --runtime $runtime `
      --output publish `
      --self-contained true
  displayName: dotnet publish for ${{ parameters.runtime }}
  debugPreference: Continue
  verbosePreference: Continue
  informationPreference: Continue
```

I get the following errors in the "Run pipeline" GUI before I can even start a build:

```
/deploy/build_webapp.yml (Line: 49, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'debugPreference'
/deploy/build_webapp.yml (Line: 50, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'verbosePreference'
/deploy/build_webapp.yml (Line: 51, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'informationPreference'
```

[image]

This one isn't specifically related to the `dotnet publish` command failing, but it's just one more weird aspect of this. Using those Preference properties shouldn't cause a failure since they're [clearly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) as supported with the pwsh task.

The only way I've been able to get `dotnet publish` working is by switching to the `PowerShell@2` task and running the `dotnet publish` command in a file:

`Publish.ps1`:

```
param($config, $runtime)

dotnet publish WebApp `
  --configuration $config `
  --runtime $runtime `
  --output publish `
  --self-contained true
```

And in my pipeline YAML:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: deploy/Publish.ps1
    arguments: ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} ${{ parameters.runtime }}
```

I'm completely stumped. At first, I thought that the inline `pwsh` task might have issues with the backtick characters. But that doesn't seem to be it. Why does the `pwsh` task not work as I expect?

Comment: You define a `$config` variable in your PS script but don't use it. That's not intended, I'd guess. Also, print the values of your variables before calling `dotnet publish` to verify the values are expected.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in this directory? You're doing "dotnet publish WebApp" Try "dotnet publish .\WebApp.csproj", or whatever is your project file name.

Comment: Also, are you sure your first snippet is not an instance of [steps.pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-pwsh?view=azure-pipelines)?

Comment: In the inline version you use `$buildConfiguration` which does not appeaer to be defined.  Did you mean to use `$config` there?

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing. You're right, it was the fact that I was using `$buildConfiguration` instead of `$config`. What a mess, I spent hours on this and the error messages just weren't helping at all. I wish I knew a way to struggle less on this in the future. In this case all I needed was an extra pair of eyes... I'm not sure if I should delete this question (since it's misleading) or accept someone's comment as the answer.

Comment: Also I find it concerning that there's two `pwsh` tasks: One in `steps.pwsh` (which I never even knew about) and a short-form for the Powershell@2 task that also uses `pwsh`.